# Calculate the value of a series using z-transform

Tags: sequences-and-series, z-transform

I want to calculate the value of the following series

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\big(\frac{2}{5}\big)^n$

For this I use the z-transform which gives:

$X(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\big(\frac{2}{5}\big)^nz^{-n}$

From the table of z-transforms, we have $a^n=\frac{z}{z-a}$, thus, with $a=\frac{2}{5}$:

$z-transform: a^n =\frac{z}{z-\frac{2}{5}}$

but from here, I am not sure what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use the fact that$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty x^n=\frac{x^k}{1-x}$$when $|x|<1$?

Comment: Is it an alternative, or is it the only way? I have in my table $a^n=\frac{z}{z-a}$. Since $a$ is some constant, and $2/5$ is too, why use $x$?

Comment: What is the relation between $x(z)$ and $X(z)$?

Comment: I was suggesting that you use $x=\frac25$. Then, the sum of your series is$$\frac{2/5}{1-2/5}=\frac23.$$

Comment: What is the relation between $X(z)$, $x_n$ and $x(n)$?

Comment: It was not from a z-transform table? I have to use some of the transforms from the table. This is why. @Gary, I changed the notation to $x_n$, as $X(z)=\sum_0^\infty x_nz^{-n}$

Comment: But then $x_n=(2/5)^n$. Sorry, but your whole post does not make sense at all.

Comment: You are right, I made a correction

Comment: You gave an integral for $X(z)$ that has a $z^{-n}$ in it but $X(z)$ does not depend on $n$, and your integral does not depend on $z$. It does not make any sense.

Comment: In the table of transforms, it says on the title of the left  column: "series, x_n":  and the relevant entry is $a^n$. Then on  the adjacent column it says in the title "z-transform, $X(z)=\sum_0^\infty x_nz^{-n}$ and on the related entry to "a_n" it says $\frac{z}{z-a}$. Then the actual inverse z-transform formula is $v(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint V(z)z^{n-1}dz$

Comment: Yes that is just because of the geometric series, no need for fancy words lik z-transform in this case. But it does not answer the problem regarding your integral formula. Shouldn't it be a formula for $x_n$ rather than $X(z)$? And with $2\pi i$ and not $2\pi$ in it? Apologise, but the whole post gives me the impression that you have no idea about what you are doing and why are you doing it.

Comment: You're right, I am mixing bananas and potatoes here.

Comment: The answer to you current version is this: put $z=1$. The answer is $1/(1-2/5)=5/3$.

Comment: This is what I though too, by looking at the lower limit of the sum, but is that the "method"? Take the lower limit and insert it in the transform?

Comment: No, you are not looking at the lower limit at all. Just look at your series formula for $X(z)$ and see what $X(1)$ is.

Comment: By putting z=1 in X(z) gives the number $a_n$ in the formula. So that is what one searches for, the right value of z which isolates $a_n?$

Comment: Basically. Btw, do you know that $$
\frac{w}{{1 - w}} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {w^n } =w+w^2+w^3+\ldots,
$$ for $|w|<1$? This called the geoemtric series.

Comment: That is a Laurent series? No I didn't know this

Comment: Funny, it is impossible to study complex analysis without knowing it. This is the most basic power series you can imagine. This is why it would be better to take proper courses istead of self study. Or use a proper book in complex analysis that teaches you from the basics.

Comment: I just got a D in complex analysis, but I have been under rough weather in the last weeks, so some details simply vanish.